# asp dot net web config key Base URL issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I got an issue during test my asp dot net web based application. In the Page there is an "Slip button" and when I click the button new pop up page should open with details.
 But i got server error '/' 404 error instead of page. After went some analysis found that in my web.config it is mentioned as below

```
<add key="BaseURL" value="http://xxxx.xx.xxx.com/arf/" />
```

I changed to localhost as below

```
<add key="BaseURL" value="http://localhost/arf/" />
```

it is working fine. why it is working when I changed to localhost. **This is in windows server**.

The same issue occurs in **Production** ( the application runs in )**HP Unix environment**.

How to fix this in Production Do I need to changed to localhost or How the url works with Domain name.

Any thing I need to change in IIS.Please help on this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Post the code that actually makes the call. A 404 is pretty straightforward and *not* affected by the domain part of the URL. It means the server *did* receive the request, but the relative path doesn't exist. It's not about Unix, Windows, production or debug. It could mean that the application wasn't deployed to the target server at all, or that the virtual directory is wrong. What is the *full* URL? Have you tried browsing to it with a browser or Postman?

Comment: This is the Path working with Local host http://localhost/arf/View.aspx?ID=A-240&RetURL=Login.aspx but if I mention domain name it is showing server error '/'

Comment: Yes, you would need to point to the current domain on which your application is running. For example: `http://yourdomain.com/` would be the `BaseURL`

Comment: if I add domain name it is not working instead of localhost. If I specify localhost it is working

Comment: @Maxtech Where is it working when you specify `localhost` ? It should be on your local environment. If you want to run on the server, specify the path where your application is hosted.